# how to avoid vim visual block selecting entire line when going down

Tags: visual

I have this sample log:

```
2023-05-21T10:29:26: Requesting: /search
2023-05-21T10:29:26: {
2023-05-21T10:29:26:   personId: ‘***-****-****-*****',
2023-05-21T10:29:26:   skip: 0,
2023-05-21T10:29:26:   limit: 11,
2023-05-21T10:29:26:   useCache: false,
2023-05-21T10:29:26:   companyFilters: {},
2023-05-21T10:29:26:   additionalFilters: { linkedinIdentifier: [ ‘identifier' ] }
2023-05-21T10:29:26: }
```

I usually do the vim visual block to quickly remove the timestamps. I do that by going on the first line, hitting <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, then hitting <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to go to the last line, then moving to the right (by hitting <kbd>l</kbd>) until i reach the `:` and hitting <kbd>d</kbd>

The problem is that on my first step, all the text is selected like so
[image]

how do I avoid doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The correct sequence is:

1. `Ctrl+v` (`<C-v>` in Vim lingo) to enter visual-block mode

   [image: step1]
2. `G` to move the cursor to last line

   [image: step2]
3. `E` to move the cursor to the end of the current WORD (see `:help WORD`)

   [image: step3]

Your screenshot tells me that either…

- you are in visual mode (not visual-block mode), in which case you probably didn't press the correct combo: `Ctrl+v`,
- or you have pressed some more keys that you didn't mention.